# Cross Domain Image Upload in JSONP with WCF

Tags: jquery, jsonp

I need to use only JSONP to upload image from client side and sending file streaming to WCF service hosting.

But I cannot implement and cannot find the way how to do it.

If anybody know please help me how to do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot really stream the image using jsonp.

You could base 64 encode the image bytes and add them to the query string, however you'd be limited to file sizes that result in a query string less than the max url size for the client (browser) in question.

To overcome the max image size problem, you could chunk the image into bytes and make many requests to the image endpoint, having encoded the current chunk number and how many chunks there are etc into the query string such that the image can be recreated on the server (and potentially a unique image upload ID), however this would rely upon sticky sessions or a shared data store between your servers in order for the image to possibly be recreated when you have multiple servers.

Alternatively (not using jsonp):

- the iframe trick as covered in @SebastienRenauld's answer.
- WebSockets